# Ruby Rails Loop in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that I want to use to generate reports from, my first report works fine it's simply a sorted output of my CSEmployee table.  However my second report isn't giving me what I would expect.  Each CS_Employee can have multiple time_entries in the TimeEntry table associated with it.  I have indexed the table and created a has_many\belongs_to relationship and all seems to work just fine in my other views.  My second report needs to show all associated time_entries for each CS_Employee for a given time period.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def cs_employees
  @cs_employees = CsEmployee.all
  @cs_employee = @cs_employees.order(:cs_name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @cs_employee.to_csv }
    format.xlsx #{ send_data @cs_employee.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
  end

def schedules
  @start_date = params[:start_date] || 2.weeks.ago
  @end_date = params[:end_date] || Date.today
  @cs_employee = CSEmployee.all
  @cs_employees.each do |cs_employee|
    @cs_employee = cs_employee.find(params[:cs_employee_id])
    @time_entries = @cs_employee.time_entries.find(params[:id])
    @time_entries.each do |time_entry|
      tschedules = time_entry.where(:date => (params[:start_date]).to_date..(params[:end_date]).to_date)
      @schedules += tschedules if tschedules
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to Debug for @schedules there is nothing in the variable.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting your `@cs_employees` variable before you call it into the each loop?

Comment: I had @csemployees = CSEmployee.all, but I had removed it trying to see if I got an error or something to fail.  either way I get the same result, nothing.  I've also tried to comment out the .where and just get all time_entries.  Still nothing.  I've added the call to the CSEmployee table back in.

Comment: Your `@cs_employee = cs_employee.find(prarams[:cs_employee_id])` line doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you using a find method on a single model entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not seem to be populating your `@cs_employees` variable when you call `@cs_employees.each`

Also, there is way too much business logic in your controller. Move it to your model or a concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
def schedules
  @start_date = params[:start_date] || 2.weeks.ago
  @end_date = params[:end_date] || Date.today
  @cs_employees = CsEmployee.all
  @cs_employees.each do |cs_employee|
    ....
  end
end
```

Comment: Downvote because there is no explanation of the code

Comment: @CarlMarkham does not explain the code? if you compare the original method with the method that you added it is clearly missing obtain all `CsEmployee`.

Answer (score 0):

So, after getting responses to this question and trying some of the suggestions, it turns out my loops were a mess.  I ended up moving the logic to the model where, as it was pointed out to me, it belonged.  The resulting code is way more simple.  Here is what it looks like now.

This is what I have in the model, the joins allow me to access all the fields I need for all my reports, not just the schedule report.

```
  def self.report(start_date, end_date)
    Costcenter.joins(:time_entries)
    CsEmployee.joins(:time_entries)
    Maintenancecode.joins(:time_entries)
    Unit.joins(:time_entries)
    Workcode.joins(:time_entries)
    TimeEntry.where( :date => start_date..end_date )
  end
```

Here is he code I now have in my controller:

```
  def schedules
    @start_date = params[:start_date] || 2.weeks.ago.to_date
    @end_date = params[:end_date] || Date.today
    @schedule_report = TimeEntry.report(@start_date, @end_date)
  end
```

Thanks for all of the help and getting me lined out as to where my code belonged in the first place.